# Force sudo to ask for password once from outside sudoers

Tags: linux, shell, sudo, sudoers

I'm trying to hack together my own Android app that opens an SSH connection to my computer, and sends commands.

I am aiming to keep the interactivity of this process to a minimum, to make it have the feel of a remote control.

I've added a sudo "switch" that when activated will ask for a sudo password that then will run a command x to be run as `sudo -S -p '' x` and then the password will be sent to the STDIN.

Problem is if the login fails, the command will then wait for another 2 password attempts, adding interactivity that I don't want!

I know I can edit `passwd_tries` in the `sudoers` file, but I rather know if there was a  way to set this as an argument with sudo or is it also an enviroment variable that can be set?

Anyone know? Or is this not allowed for security reasons?

Comment: Could you just have it check and, if the password failed, just do a couple quick "spam" messages to use up the next two password attempts? Certainly not a very nice solution, but it's an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing through `man sudo` and `sudoers` file, I don't see see any way to achieve the wanted behavior.

Possible reasons:
 Number of password retries can not be increased, from a security standpoint. While decreasing number of password retries, could be achieved, I guess it wasn't needed.

Possible solution:
Using -S, since it fails immediately if password if incorrect:

```
echo <passwd> | sudo -S ls
```

Comment: Not quite fails immediately, just sudo takes the same <passwd> for each attempt. But it does do the job!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a separate user account and configure your `sudoers` file to grant access without a password at all.

```
myuser    ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Alternatively, set up the user to have a `uid` of `0` which effectively is a second root account.

This removes any secret password from you Android app. Really, avoid storing shared secrets like user passwords in plain text.